# I can't install sweetalert2 in Angular

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface, sweetalert2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjbEE.png)

This issue. Can you help me ?

I tried other installation instructions. I tried them all but couldn't find the solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR782.png)

Comment: Kindly follow the guidelines as mentioned in the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your angular version? It seems the sweetalert2 version you're trying to install is incompatible with the version some of your other packages. Can you share your `package.json` file? You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136974/sweetalert-is-not-running-i-got-an-error-on-its-ts-file
Also, it's always a good idea to share the error itself instead of an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the package `ngx-spinner` and not with `sweetalert2`.
The error message tells you that `ngx-spinner` is not supporting Angular 15. So you can downgrade your angular version. Replacing `ngx-spinner` or waiting for an update for `ngx-spinner`.